# Solving $\sec\theta - 1 = \left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right) \tan\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve 
>   $$\sec\theta - 1 = \left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right) \tan\theta$$

My try :[image]

Is there any process possible for this equation? Please share it.

Comment: Your solution is correct.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{\sec2y-1}{\tan2y}=\dfrac{1-\cos2y}{\sin2y}=\tan y$$

Alternatively,  $$\sqrt2-1=\dfrac{\sec2y-1}{\tan2y}=\csc2y-\cot2y$$

$$\iff\csc2y+\cot2y=\dfrac1{\csc2y-\cot2y}=?$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Dividing tan theta both side you get - $$\frac{1-\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}= \sqrt{2}-1$$ Now square it on both sides ,  and solving further you will reach the solution.

Additional hints: $$\frac{1-\cos{x}}{1+\cos{x}}= 3-2\sqrt{2}$$ $$\cos{x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $$  and you are done.

Comment: Are the answers of yours the same of main equation?

Comment: two points: 1) division by tan theta deprived of one root; 2) squaring introduced extra root.